# proof about integer being written as two integer squares

Tags: proof-verification

**Problem:** If $q$ is an integer that can be expressed as the sum of integer squares,show that both $2q$ and $5q$ can also be espressed as the sum of two integer squares.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pythagorean theorem. What if $q = 1 + 4$? What is $c$?

Comment: $q$ is not given to be a square, so $c$ may not be an integer.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i have missed it all up, let me edit.

Comment: one question : in general why can't i suppose $q$ to be the square of some number which squared does give me an integer (even if that number isn't an integer)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $q=a^2+b^2$, then $(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=2q$.

For $5q$, use (a special case of) *Brahmagupta's identity*:
$$(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)=(ax-by)^2+(ay+bx)^2$$

Comment: $+1$. For such a nice solution for the case $5q$.

Answer (score 0):

For $5q$, we can write it as

$$(a+2b)^2 + (2a-b)^2=a^2+4ab+4b^2+4a^2-4ab+b^2$$
$$=5a^2+5b^2=5 (a^2+b^2)=5 q$$

We only need to prove that $a+2b$ and $2a-b$ are integers.